# Which SQL Server ODBC driver do you use?

Tags: sql-server, vba, odbc, ms-access-2010

Various Windows 7 and Windows 10 computers in my company have different ODBC drivers installed. I found this out when trying to create DSNs or DSN-less connection strings for some VB/VBA applications to connect to our SQL Server. Some machines have ODBC SQL Server Driver x, or SQL Server Native Client or something else. How do you know where these all came from, what they're all doing there, and which to use.

My uneducated hypothesis: SQL Server Native Driver 11.0 is somehow installed by default with Windows 7 or Office 2016 or some such. SQL Server Driver 14.x is perhaps installed if you have SQL Server Management Studio....? Am I even close? Do they do different things? Does it matter which you use?

(BTW, I have found, whenever possible, it's much easier to use DSN-less strings because then if a user needs to run your application you don't have to go to their machine and build a DSN for them. I even have code to convert linked SQL Server tables in MS Access to replace the DSN connect string with a DSN-less string.)

Comment: The MDAC driver is [apparently shipped with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025550/11683), the rest is installed separately and there is no point in guessing which third party software does it. You pick the driver you want when you develop your application and you distribute that driver or list it in your dependencies.

Comment: Almost everyone in the building here seems to already have the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 installed though; I don't know if it came with Windows or with Office. Is that the MDAC driver?